# Parsing CSV Data from one column with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Lets say I have column "OU":

```
OU                      
CORP:Jenny Smith:    
STORE:Mary Poppins:  
STORE:Tony Stark:
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:    
NEWS:Peter Parker:
NEWS:Clark Kent:
```

I want to parse this column up to the first ":" and keep only the words before the ":". Then any word that repeats is left only at one. So the finished data should look like this:

```
OU                      
CORP
STORE     
NEWS
```

Would I need to do something in the `pandas.read_csv(file, usecols=['OU'])` when I read the original CSV file?

---

In reference to an answer below, this is also how that one row looks in a text editor:

```
 OU                      
 CORP:Jenny Smith:   
 "CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:" 
 STORE:Mary Poppins:  
 STORE:Tony Stark:
 STORE:Carmen Sandiego:    
 NEWS:Peter Parker:
 NEWS:Clark Kent:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the semicolon as separator and supply the column title manually, skipping the first title row of the csv file. Then you [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates):

```
pd.read_csv(file, sep=":", header=None, skiprows=1, usecols=[0], names=['OU']).drop_duplicates()
```

Result:

```
      OU
0   CORP
1  STORE
4   NEWS
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have one tiny issue, I noticed I have one row that looks like this: "CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:" so I have two CORPs, one just CORP by itself and then another CORP but with the whole row still showing like this: CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:. Would I be able to do something else in the pd.read_csv() or would this just need to be fixed in a df[df["OU"].str.contains("CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:")==False]?

Comment: hm, I can't imagine how this can happen: adding `CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:` to the sample csv works perfectly fine. Can you verify if this line indeed contains a `:` after CORP? Can you show this line and the following line?

Comment: Yes it looks exactly like this CORP:John Smith:,John Smith: , but, I did notice in a regular text editor that this one row has CORP:John Smith:,John Smith: but in quotes. So it looks like "CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:" while the rest don't look like this. In excel you can't see this. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, this definitely helps :). Set `quoting=3` ([quotes are treated as regular characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE)) and strip any trailing quotes: `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=":", header=None, skiprows=1, usecols=[0], names=['OU'],quoting=3).OU.str.strip('"').drop_duplicates()`

Comment: No problem, you answered very quickly I didn't even see this lol. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I am getting a tiny error for the io.StringIO(s) in my code when I run it. I imported io, but I get a `NameError: name 's' is not defined. Did you mean: 'os'?` error. I tried with `pd.read_csv(file, io.StringIO(s), sep=":", header=None, skiprows=1, usecols=[0], names=['OU'],quoting=3).OU.str.strip('"').drop_duplicates()` and `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=":", header=None, skiprows=1, usecols=[0], names=['OU'],quoting=3).OU.str.strip('"').drop_duplicates()` but it won't run. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: oh, sorry - it was just for my testing, you should of course use `pd.read_csv(file, sep=":", header=None, skiprows=1, usecols=[0], names=['OU'],quoting=3).OU.str.strip('"').drop_duplicates()`. My bad.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us. Thank you so much, it works great now :)